# Move Div up by 20px - But keep the border

Tags: html, css

i have three `<div>`s and want to move the second one up.

Currently i'm doing this with `position: relative; top: -20px;` - That works pretty well.

Only downside is: There's a gap (of 20px) between the second `<div>` and the third `<div>` (which is under the second div).

So, i want to keep the border around all three divs, so that `top: -20px` is not an alternative for the third row.

I have this illustrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/w2PGF/1/

My Markup:

```
<div id="border">
    <div class="firstRow">foo</div>
    <div class="secondRow">bar</div>
    <div class="thirdRow">foobar</div>
</div>​
```

My CSS:

```
#border {
    border: 5px solid #000;
}
.firstRow {
    background-color: cyan;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
.secondRow {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
}
.thirdRow {
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.
​

Comment: Why do you want to move the 2nd div up?

Comment: because of an overlapping tab selecting area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.secondRow { margin-bottom: -20px }
```

Comment: arrr ... that's it. thank you. that's the moment i need to slap myself ;)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `position: relative` and instead of `top: -20px` you should add `margin-top: -20px`

Like so: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/w2PGF/7/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `top: -20px` and add `margin-top: -20px` to `.secondRow`

So `.secondRow` would look like this:
.

```
secondRow {
    margin-top: -20px;
    border: 3px solid yellow;
    background-color: grey;
    height: 50px;
}
```

Check this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2PGF/6/